# Redux state updates don't pass through to a method within my component's stateless function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

I have a stateless function that returns a component for my Redux/React Native application. In it are some defined helper functions:

```
export default function TasksList (props) {
  let ds = new ListView.DataSource({
    rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2
  });

  const _onLongPress = (rowData) => {
    props.changeCurrentlyEditedTask(rowData.index, rowData)

    props.navigator.push({
      component: EditTask,
      title: props.selectedTaskText,
      leftButtonTitle: 'Cancel',
      rightButtonTitle: 'Save',
      onLeftButtonPress: () => _cancelEditingTask(),
      onRightButtonPress: () => _saveEditedTask()
    })
  }

  const _cancelEditingTask = () => {
    props.navigator.pop();
    props.resetSelectedTask();
  }

  const _saveEditedTask = () => {
    props.saveEditedTask()
    props.navigator.pop();
  }

  const dataSource = ds.cloneWithRows(props.listOfTasks);

  return (
    <View style={ styles.tasksListContainer }>
      <TextInput
        autoCorrect={ false }
        onChangeText={ (text) => props.onChangeText(text) }
        onSubmitEditing={ () => props.addTask(props.text) }
        returnKeyType={ 'done' }
        style={ styles.tasksListTextInput }
        value={ props.text } />
      <ListView
        automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={ false }
        dataSource={ dataSource }
        enableEmptySections={ true }
        renderRow={ (rowData, secctionID, rowID) => {
          return (
            <TasksListCell
              completed={ rowData.completed }
              id={ rowID }
              onLongPress={ (rowID) => _onLongPress(rowData) }
              onPress={ (rowID) => props.changeCompletionStatus(rowData.index) }
              text={ rowData.text }
              completed={ rowData.completed }
              formattedDate={ rowData.hasOwnProperty('formattedDate') ? rowData.formattedDate : undefined } />
          )
        }
      }
      style={ styles.tasksListView } />
    </View>
  );
};
```

Whenever my Redux state is changed, its changes proliferate through to TasksList as intended. However, `_saveEditedTask` fails to receive those updates.

If I attempt to pass `props` as an argument to my `saveEditedTask` dispatch method in my container, it does not receive the updated state that the parent `TasksList` function does.

How can I fix this code so that `_saveEditedTask` receives the most up-to-date `props` from its parent `TasksList` function?

Comment: It might be worth it to connect more of these components to Redux.

Comment: Push and pop are mutating functions, so using `props.navigator.push()` and `props.navigator.pop()` are mutating your props.   This is a huge red flag in React code.

Comment: @Scimonster At this time, EditTask is connected to Redux via a container. TasksListCell, the other custom component, is not yet connected. Will connecting it send me down the right path?

Comment: @DanielBank thanks for the heads up; how would you recommend I handle my navigation?

Comment: @RichardKho It might help.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment the _saveEditedTask function is defined and in fact does have access to the props of the TasksList component.

The issue is that you are not passing this function as a prop to any children in the render method.

You should give the below prop to one of the children in the render method of your component. If you don't do this then the function will never be invoked.

```
onSave={ () => _saveEditedTask() }
```